# Looking for template "Category"

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Good morning everyone!

I'm working on a dynamic web project where the user need to collect data from a **selection** of units. So far, so good. The user should select the units from one column to the second one.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I'm looking for a template. My problem is: My native language is German and i don't know **how to call those design/template categories** to google it.

Does somebody have a suggestion for me, or a hint where I can find good templates?

And for you guys I reveal my awesome MS Paint Skills that you get an idea:

[image: awesome MS Paint Skills]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right keyword for it:  **duallistbox**

[image]